# wordpress IE hack to have menu on line

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a menu that looks fine in FF but in chrome and IE it is not sitting right on the line. Can anyone help. I have tried many CSS hacks but they have not worked in wordpress. I even tried external IE sheet and somewhere it was getting over written.

site 
site remove for other purposes.

chrome and IE it is wrong.

Comment: okay I have in IE finally but chrome it is off. I added this to bottom of header.php                                      <!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ie.css" media="screen" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->

Comment: Okay now it is working in all browsers. This is for chrome    @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {#nav ul.sf-menu, #nav-top ul.sf-menu { display: inline-block; position: relative; top: 55px;padding-top:2px;}}

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem as yours

IE version 6-8 have so many problem unlike 9 its better.

if you are using list on menu use this

display:inline;

Comment: see above as i finally figured it out. I just made css hacks for each browser.